# Access Denied When Enumerating Through Process Modules C++

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

I am trying to enumerate through a process's modules to get the memory address range it operates in. This function works with other processes fine. However, on the particular process which I had intended to analyze I get error code 5, ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. Note that at position 1 I get error code 0 and at position 2 I get error code 5. I understand that some kernel objects can be protected which could explain this error code. Is this the reason? If so, is it possible to work around that?

```
int PrintModules(DWORD processID)
{

HMODULE hMods[1024];
HANDLE hProcess;
DWORD cbNeeded;
unsigned int i;

// Print the process identifier.

printf("\nProcess ID: %u\n", processID);

// Get a handle to the process.

hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,
    FALSE, processID);
std::cout << "POSITION 1 : " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
if (NULL == hProcess)
{
    return 1;
}
// Get a list of all the modules in this process.

if (EnumProcessModules(hProcess, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded))
{
    for (i = 0; i < (cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++)
    {
        TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];

        // Get the full path to the module's file.

        if (GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, hMods[i], szModName,
            sizeof(szModName) / sizeof(TCHAR)))
        {
            // Print the module name and handle value.

            _tprintf(TEXT("\t%s (0x%08X)\n"), szModName, hMods[i]);
        }
    }
}
else {
    std::cout << "POSITION 2 : " <<GetLastError() << std::endl;
}

// Release the handle to the process.

CloseHandle(hProcess);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it no option to run your application under local administrative rights or set the right privileges for your process (`AdjustTokenPrivileges()`)?

Comment: I have tried to run the application as administrator and had the same issues.

Comment: Please use ProcessExplorer or an equivalent tool to check the security information of your process. Some like anti virus programs or system processes do not allow a read for other processes.

Comment: Process Explorer shows that the process is not protected and the system has read/write permissions. I have already adjusted token privileges.

Comment: PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS is a big demand, that allows you to mess with a process in any imaginable way.  When you enumerate *all* running processes then you almost always encounter one that you don't have sufficient access rights for to do that.  You'll have to skip it.  Do consider lowering your demand, seems you don't need more than PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION.

Comment: @HansPassant - `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` not enough. need also `PROCESS_VM_READ` because this api read from target process virtual memory

Comment: and if you say true, that error in call `EnumProcessModules` - task not in any privileges or process access at all - you already open process with all access. however I very doubt that `EnumProcessModules` can return error access denied on process handle opened with all access

Answer (score 1):

ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED means your handle is invalid.  You're getting and invalid handle when you call OpenProcess for one of two reasons.

Either your process id is wrong or you're not running as administrator.  You need to run as administrator for PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS permissions.